# Divergence Funtion result issue and plot line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wrote a code for divergence with an array in PineScript 5. I have a problem comparing the hypothetical line between two divergence and candle close points.

Because in my code I compare the last pivot with the previous pivots, I changed the code in several ways and it didn't work, please help me.

```
//@version=5
indicator("divergence 2")
plot(na)
l_prd = input.int(defval = 5, title = "Left Pivot Period", minval = 1, maxval = 50)
r_prd = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Right Pivot Period", minval = 1, maxval =5) 
source = input.source(close, "Source")
maxpp = input.int(defval = 10, title = "Maximum Pivot Points to Check", minval = 1, maxval = 20)
maxbars = input.int(defval = 100, title = "Maximum Bars to Check", minval = 30, maxval = 200)
dontconfirm = input(defval = false, title = "Don't Wait for Confirmation")

// get indicators
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14) // RSI
[macd, signal, deltamacd] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9) // MACD
os = macd

// Check if we get new Pivot High Or Pivot Low
float ph = ta.pivothigh((source == close ? close : high), l_prd, r_prd)
float pl = ta.pivotlow((source == close ? close : low), l_prd, r_prd)
// plotshape(ph and showpivot, text = "H",  style = shape.labeldown, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.red, location = location.abovebar, offset = -prd)
// plotshape(pl and showpivot, text = "L",  style = shape.labelup, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.lime, location = location.belowbar, offset = -prd)

// keep values and positions of Pivot Highs/Lows in the arrays
var int maxarraysize = 20
var ph_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var pl_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var ph_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)
var pl_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)
var ph_os = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)
var pl_os = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)

// add PHs to the array
if ph
    array.unshift(ph_positions, bar_index-r_prd)
    array.unshift(ph_vals, ph)
    array.unshift(ph_os, os[r_prd])
    if array.size(ph_positions) > maxarraysize
        array.pop(ph_positions)
        array.pop(ph_vals)
        array.pop(ph_os)



plot(close)
nrd = false
div = false
////negative Regular Divergences
for x = 0 to maxpp
    len = bar_index - array.get(ph_positions, x)
    if array.get(ph_positions, x) == 0 or len > maxbars
        break
    else if ph and ph > array.get(ph_vals, x) and os < array.get(ph_os, x)
        nrd := true
        slope1 = math.abs(close-close[len])/len
        slope2 = math.abs(os-os[len])/len
        cross = 0
        not_cross = 0
        int z = na
        for y=1 to len - 1 
            if (close[y] < close - slope1*y) and (os[y] < os + slope2*y)
                not_cross := not_cross+1
            else
                cross := cross+1
                break
        if not_cross ==len-2
            div := true
            line.new(x1=bar_index-r_prd ,y1=ph ,x2=array.get(ph_positions, x)  ,y2=array.get(ph_vals, x) ,color = color.red)
```

Comment: hi i change 3 last line of code to                                                                                                                         if not_cross 
            div := true
            line.new(x1=bar_index-r_prd ,y1=ph ,x2=array.get(ph_positions, x)  ,y2=array.get(ph_vals, x) ,color = color.red)     and line plotted but not true

Comment: when you want to make changes on your code, or you have some important to add/change to your post, then please use the [Edit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77211160/edit).